# How to scroll left or right to a certain div (For Image Slider) in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, horizontal-scrolling

How to scroll left or right to a certain div (For Image Slider) in React functional component

Ex:

- I have a parent div slider which contains of 4 child divs' horizontally and I have 2 arrow buttons to scroll left and right.
- On click of my left and right arrow button's my divs' should move accordingly